# angular-ui-tree drop INTO node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-tree

I am currently using [Angular UI Tree](https://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/connected-trees) connected trees. Tree1 has only one level of depth while Tree2 is unlimited in depth. I need to be able to drag any item from Tree2 ***INTO*** Tree1 items and catch that event.

Just to clarify: In effect Tree1 is the top level items of Tree2 and this allows me to easily move items between the overall data structure.

I could not find a way to do this under the current documentation, so I did the following:
On Tree1 I disabled drop:

```
<div ui-tree="tree1Options" id="tree1-root" data-nodrop-enabled='true'>
```

and then on Tree2 I added the following call backs:

```
<div ui-tree="tree2Options" id="tree2-root">

$scope.tree2Options = {
dropped : function(event) {
      console.log("dropped" + event);
    },

    dragStop : function(event) {
      console.log("dragStop" + event);
    },

    beforeDrop : function(event) {
      console.log("beforeDrop" + event);
    },
}
```

When I drag from Tree2 onto Tree1 no placeholder is shown (which is fine), but I cannot get which item the drop was on from the destination. Seems like the dest is actually the source.

Any ideas? Also, if you know a better way to achieve DROP INTO?

Comment: Having the same issue, did anyone find a 'drop-into' solution from Tree 1 to Tree 2?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one set of callbacks per scope, perhaps its possible to add a flag  to the data coming in so it knows which different model its coming from to run a diffeent function under a case switch within the one callback